# Deploying function to convert a string to a R vectors

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a R data frame of the form:

```
column
"[22, 55]"
"[99, 100]"
"[100, 49]"
```

Goal:

```
column
c(22, 55)
c(99, 100)
c(100, 49)
```

---

This function will do that

```
to_numeric_cols <- function(string){
  to_return <- substring(string, 2, nchar(string) - 1)
  to_return <- c(strsplit(to_return, ",")[[1]])
  to_return <- list(as.numeric(to_return))
  return(to_return)
}
```

and it works when deployed via a for loop,

i.e.,

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
   df[["column"]][i] <- to_numeric_cols(df[["column"]][i])
}
```

However this is R and thus this solution is sure to be (and is!) very slow.

I tried this:

```
df[["column"]] <- apply(df[,c('column'), drop = F], 1, function(x) to_numeric_cols(x))
```

However, this returns rows of the form:
`list(c(22, 55))`

I know apply (at least as I'm using it) is not appropriate here. 
How can I accomplish this in a R-thonic way?

---

Structure:

```
nm <- c(   "[22, 55]"
         , "[99, 100]"
         , "[100, 49]")
df <- data.frame(nm)
```

Comment: Are there always two numbers in your 'column'?

Comment: For this specific problem, yes. However, a solution that will work with more than two numbers would be very handy...

Comment: And do you really want all numbers in one column? Wouldn't one new column per number  be more practical?

Comment: I see you point, but I'd have hundreds of columns if I did that (I have several different columns like this).

Comment: Depends on how you plan to use them, number of columns doesn't need to be a problem.

Comment: I appreciate that. However, I am analyzing data from a rather complex experimental design. Frankly, conceptually manipulating the data if it is distributed over many columns would be very taxing.

Comment: Does this help you? `do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\]", "",unlist(df)),","),as.numeric))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach in base-R which can deal with multiple numbers and creates a column of numerical vectors. We use vectorized approaches to sanitize our data and split. Unfortunately, as.numeric cannot do this so we wrap it in lapply.

```
nm <- c(   "[22, 55]"
           , "[99, 100]"
           , "[100, 49]"
           , "[100, 49, 48]")
df <- data.frame(column=nm,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

First, we sanitize our data and remove the brackets

```
df$c2 <- gsub("\\[|\\]","",df$column)
```

Then we strsplit (vectorized) and as.numeric (unfortunately less vectorized):

```
df$c3 <- lapply(strsplit(df$c2,","),as.numeric)
```

(Can be done in one step: `df$c3 <- lapply(strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\]","",df$column),","), as.numeric)`

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ column: chr  "[22, 55]" "[99, 100]" "[100, 49]" "[100, 49, 48]"
 $ c2    : chr  "22, 55" "99, 100" "100, 49" "100, 49, 48"
 $ c3    :List of 4
  ..$ : num  22 55
  ..$ : num  99 100
  ..$ : num  100 49
  ..$ : num  100 49 48
```

Comment: I should have been using regex from the start to parse the string... At any rate, thanks for the solution.

Comment: Yw. If you do decide to go for one column per value, check out the excellent splitstackshape-package by@anandamahto. It even type-converts.

Comment: I certainly will check it out. Again, thank you very much.